# failed to open stream: HTTP request failed in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to get a string from a file using Codeigniter.

This is in my controller:

```
$var = file_get_contents(base_url().'file/path/key_file.txt');
```

But I get the following error when the above is called:

> [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!

It works fine on my localserver but when moved to the live web server I get the above error.

The file is definitely there, in the correct place, as I can access it directly.

Comment: Are you sure that the base_url() is correct ?

Comment: Yes it is correct. The URL the error shows is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Now most hosting providers block the `furl_open` parameter which allows you to use `file_get_contents()`. It is better and safe to use `CURL`.

```
<?php
$curl_handle=curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL,base_url().'file/path/key_file.txt');
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Your application name');
$query = curl_exec($curl_handle);
curl_close($curl_handle);
?>
```

Please ensure that PHP CURL is enabled in your system.

Answer (score 0):

Try `getcwd()` insted of `base_url()`

```
$var = file_get_contents(getcwd().'/file/path/key_file.txt');
```

May be your server is not allow open file from url,Or change  in your `php.ini`

```
allow_url_fopen=1;
```